# Truecrypt file containers suddenly empty

Tags: linux, encryption, truecrypt

I have multiple truecrypt file containers on my Google Drive. They all contain lots of files and folders that has worked well over the last 18 months.

Today I reinstalled my PC and went from Windows 8 to Debian. As Google Drive has no support for Linux yet I used the web interface to download my file containers to the computer.

I can successfully mount them using truecrypt, but when I browse them (for instance /media/truecrypt3/) - they are all empty. They do however occupy the correct disk space on my system.

So far I have checked that "Preserve modification timestamp of file containers" is disabled. I also asked my father to download the file container to his Windows machine. He's able to mount but it's empty.

How on earth can my file containers suddenly become empty because I reinstall the OS on my PC?

Comment: based on your description, I have to assume it is just coincidental  that you rebuilt your pc at the time the volumes failed. you are correct that rebuilding your PC should not have any impact on files stored on your remote storage service. you may want to try a volume check on the file system inside your volume, and see if there has been any filesystem metadata corruption.

Comment: Having multiple different files all fail at once seems... hard to believe. It's 6 containers that act the same way.

Comment: I'm not saying that the volumes going bad are coincidental to each-other; no that seems connected. its the PC rebuild that I believe coincides with the failure. what kind of filesystem was in your volumes?

Comment: They are FAT. Just installed a virtual Windows 7 and did "Check filesystem" from truecrypt on one of them. It says two hidden files which is interesting, because this particular container is supposed to have two files in it. But even with hidden files visible I can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more investigation I found that there is only one revision of each file container on Google Drive. This leads me to believe that the Google Drive folder on my Windows machine never synced changes to the cloud. This would explain the empty single revision on Internet (revision date matches creation date on all files).

Lesson learned and I will NEVER combine Google Drive and Truecrypt again. My only option now is to try to recover files locally using some kind of software. Hopefully I can get to the NTFS partition again and extract the files from my local Google Drive folder.

Comment: I was able to restore the .tc files from the local Google Drive folder. They contained all info.